# How to align a widget with dynamic width of another widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my web app, I have several pages showing DataTables with different columns and table widths.  Under each of the table, I have a sharable Navigator class and a Icon Button "+" for inserting records.  Here is how it looks like:

[image]

How do I position the "Add Icon", which is in the bottom right now, to the end, align right to the end of the table?

Side question: can I change the color or even the icon for the sorting icon?

Here is my code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Web App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.78),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 300,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Search...',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                    controller: _SearchItemController,
                    focusNode: SearchItemFocusNode,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                DataTable(
                  border: TableBorder.all(
                    width: 0.2),
                  headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Styles.TableHeaderColor;
                  }),  // Use the default value.
                  columns: getColumns(TableTitles),
                  rows: getRows(),
                  sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                  sortAscending: isAscending,
                  dataRowHeight: 50,
                  headingRowHeight: 40,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Row(
                    children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: PageNavigator(currentPage, totalPages,
                              totalRecords, _pageController, this),
                        ),
                      IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                            tooltip: 'Add Record',
                            onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

DataTable widths are set in the TableTitles class which is different in different pages:

List TableTitles = [
TableTitle(title: 'ID', width: 50),
TableTitle(title: 'Chinese Name', width: 120),
TableTitle(title: 'English Name', width: 300),
TableTitle(title: 'Zone', width: 200),
TableTitle(title: 'Edit', width: 60),
TableTitle(title: 'Delete', width: 60),
];

Comment: try `mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.start`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your button in the same widget with the form.
You can follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insert-operation-in-datatable-in-flutter/) tutorial for help.